# Google Sign Out and disconnecting not working and also facebook login integration not working

Tags: java, android

I building an simple app when i sign in through Google or Facebook from the LoginActivity the app must start a new activity and store the login data for future so that user won't have to login next time with the same account.

I have have created a custom button for the Facebook and Google login but the Facebook login not working and Once i logged in with the Google account and then i sign out from the MainActivity the Google signout method not working and the again move to MainActivity without asking for login.

I also added a button in Navigation Drawer that should sign out user but the Google account not disconnecting i don't know what is the issue because i am new to android. so please help me.

Here is the LoginActivity.java file

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    
        private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
        MaterialTextView txtLogin, txtSignUp;
        MaterialButton btnLogin;
        FrameLayout fb, google;
        ImageView fb_icon, google_icon;
        LoginButton facebook_login_button;
        SignInButton google_signIn_button;
        GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    
        SharedPreferences newsharedPreferences;
    
        public ConstraintLayout LoginLayout;
    
        public int RC_SIGN_IN = 1001;
    
        public String FBemail, FBfirstname, FBlastname, FBid, FBprofile_pic_url;
    
    
        CallbackManager callbackManager;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    
    
            txtLogin = findViewById(R.id.txtLogin);
            txtSignUp = findViewById(R.id.txtSignUp);
            fb = findViewById(R.id.fb);
            google = findViewById(R.id.g);
            fb_icon = findViewById(R.id.fb_icon);
            google_icon = findViewById(R.id.google_icon);
            facebook_login_button = findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
            google_signIn_button = findViewById(R.id.google_signIn_button);
            LoginLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.LoginLayout);
    
    
            //Google login
    
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
    
    
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    
            newsharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("UserData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    
    
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    
            txtLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
            txtSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
            facebook_login_button.setOnClickListener(this);
            google_signIn_button.setOnClickListener(this);
            fb_icon.setOnClickListener(this);
            google_icon.setOnClickListener(this);
    
    
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    
            switch (v.getId())
            {
    
            case R.id.txtSignUp:
    
            txtanimation();
            break;
    
    
            case R.id.fb_icon:
                if(v == fb_icon)
                    {
                        facebook_login_button.performClick();
                    }
    
                facebook_login_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
                facebook_login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
    
                    String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                    Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);
    
    
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
    
                            String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                            Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);
    
                            try {
                                FBfirstname = object.getString("first_name");
                                FBlastname = object.getString("last_name");
                                FBemail = object.getString("email");
                                FBid = object.getString("id");
    
                                FBprofile_pic_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + FBid + "/picture?type=normal";
    
    
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = newsharedPreferences.edit();
    
                                editor.putString("ProfileName", FBfirstname + FBlastname);
                                editor.putString("ProfileEmail", FBemail);
                                editor.putString("ProfilePhoto", FBprofile_pic_url);
                                editor.apply();
                                editor.commit();
    
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    
                                Log.i("OnCompelete", FBfirstname);
    
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
    
    
                        }
                    });
    
                    Bundle parameteres = new Bundle();
                    parameteres.putString("Fields", "id, first_name, last_name, public_profile, email");
                    request.setParameters(parameteres);
                    request.executeAsync();
    
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
    
                }
            });
    
            break;
    
    
            case R.id.google_icon:
                if(v == google_icon)
                    {
                        google_signIn_button.performClick();
                    }
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            break;
    
    
            case R.id.btnLogin:
            break;
        }
    
        }
        
        //Check for the last signed in account when activity starts.
    
        @Override
        protected void onStart () {
            super.onStart();
    
            GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
            Log.i("googleAccount", String.valueOf(account));
            updateUI(account);
        }
    
    
        //for sign out from google.
        public void googleSignOUT () {
    
    
            mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            // ...
                        }
                    });
            }
            
            // for disconnect the google account from the app.
    
        public void revokeAccess() {
            mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            // ...
                        }
                    });
        }
    
           
        // App ui will change upon the if the user logged in or not
    
            private void updateUI (GoogleSignInAccount account){
    
                if (account != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "User already logged in ", LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
    
                    String ACName = account.getDisplayName();
                    String personEmail = account.getEmail();
                    Uri personPhoto = account.getPhotoUrl();
    
                    Log.i("gphoto", String.valueOf(personPhoto));
    
    
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = newsharedPreferences.edit();
    
                    editor.putString("ProfileName", ACName);
                    editor.putString("ProfileEmail", personEmail);
                    editor.putString("ProfilePhoto", String.valueOf(personPhoto));
                    editor.apply();
                    editor.commit();
    
                   startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "User not logged in Please log in first", LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    revokeAccess();
                }
    
            }
    
    
    
            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
    
                //facebook login
                callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
                //Google Sign in
                if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                    handleSignInResult(task);
                }
            }
    
            private void handleSignInResult (Task < GoogleSignInAccount > task) {
    
    
                try {
                    GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
    
                    updateUI(account);
                } catch (ApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
    
                    new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this).setTitle("Sign In Error")
                            .setMessage(e.getStatusCode() + "\n" + GoogleSignInStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(e.getStatusCode()))
                            .setPositiveButton("Retry", null)
                            .show();
    
                    Log.i("FailedCode", "SignInResulte- Failed Code" + e.getStatusCode());
                    Log.i("StatusMessage", "SignInFailed--Reason" + e.getStatusMessage());
                }
    
            }
    
            private void txtanimation () {
    
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.txtanimation);
                txtSignUp.setTextSize(36);
                txtSignUp.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFCFF"));
    
                //to change the margin
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) txtSignUp.getLayoutParams();
                params.setMargins(100, 15, 0, 0);
                txtSignUp.setLayoutParams(params);
    
                txtSignUp.startAnimation(animation);
    
                txtLogin.setTextSize(26);
                txtLogin.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#645853"));
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams secondparams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) txtLogin.getLayoutParams();
                params.setMargins(200, 5, 0, 0);
                txtLogin.setLayoutParams(secondparams);
    
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        }
```

Here is the login_activity.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    android:background="@color/mattBlackone"
    android:id="@+id/LoginLayout">


    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:text="Login"
        app:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/Snow"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/SnowShadow"
        android:clickable="true"/>


    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSignUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/txtLogin"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        app:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/Umber"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/SnowShadow"
        android:clickable="true"/>



    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginId"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/Nblue"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/Nblue">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:hint="Email ID"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/Nblue"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/Nblue"
        >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtForgatPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forgate Password ?"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Umber"
        app:textAllCaps="false"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnLogin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/loginPassword"
        android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>



    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/loginPassword"
        app:strokeColor="@color/Nblue"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Snow"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cornerRadius="12dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/Nblue"
        android:shadowColor="@color/SnowShadow"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fb"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp">

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fb_icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/g"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
        android:clickable="true">

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/google_signIn_button"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/google_icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/google_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the MainActivity.java file in which i am performing signout process

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    TextView upperText, LowerText;
    ImageView profile_imageView;
    SharedPreferences mysharedPreferences;

    MaterialButton btn_sign_out;
    String Name, Email, Photo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);


        //To set the porfile information in the header of the navigation drawer

        mysharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("UserData", MODE_PRIVATE);



        View header = ((NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view)).getHeaderView(0);

        btn_sign_out =  findViewById(R.id.btn_log_out);
        upperText = header.findViewById(R.id.upperText);
        LowerText = header.findViewById(R.id.LowerText);
        profile_imageView = header.findViewById(R.id.profile_imageView);


        Name = mysharedPreferences.getString("ProfileName", Name);
        Email = mysharedPreferences.getString("ProfileEmail", Email);
        Photo = mysharedPreferences.getString("ProfilePhoto", Photo);

        Log.i("profile" ,Name);
        Log.i("profileEmail" ,Email);
        Log.i("profilePhoto" ,Photo);

        upperText.setText(Name);
        LowerText.setText(Email);
        Glide.with(header).load(Photo).into(profile_imageView);

        btn_sign_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginActivity loginActivity = new LoginActivity();
                loginActivity.googleSignOUT();
                loginActivity.revokeAccess();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });


        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.nav_app_bar_open_drawer_description,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.


        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.nav_log_out:

                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        style="@style/Widget.Custom.NavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_log_out"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:text="Sign Out"
                android:textColor="@color/Snow"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                app:strokeColor="@color/Dwhite"
                app:strokeWidth="1dp"
                app:cornerRadius="12dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is Manifest.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.akapplicationsinc.nillu_hair_saloon">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone tell me how to perform both logout (Facebook and Google) with a single  item or button in navigation drawer Your knowledge will teach me new things and i will admire your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sign out using this code

```
btn_sign_out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                GoogleSignIn.getClient(
                        getContext(),
                        new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).build()
                ).signOut();
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));            }
        });
```

Comment: ok i'll try it but can you tell can you tell me that why we are using this code instead of the code which is provided by Google for sign out, and why that code is not working for logout